# Deployment workflow for local, staging, and production environments (EngineYard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an AppCloud account on EngineYard.

I have a local git repository that I then push to Beanstalk.

What tools might I look into to help me out, and what's a good workflow for pushing to the staging environment on EY, then from there to the production environment after testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EngineYard has an awesome gem for managing deploys through the command line. A deploy to staging might look something like:

```
ey deploy -v -e Staging -r my_release_branch
```

then after merging code to master... to production:

```
ey deploy -v -e Production -r master
```

More at https://github.com/engineyard/engineyard